# Does App_Code in ASP.Net compile new code to a secondary temp AppDomain?

Tags: asp.net, appdomain, app-code

I am trying to better understand how the App-Code folder operates, and in particular I am curious how new objects that a new class in the App-Code folder are included in the current AppDomain.  Is a second, temporary AppDomain created in the same manner as when I compile new objects with the CodeDom?

In many ways the capability of moving new classes / objects into a Web Application is very compelling.  Rob Connery's [MVC Storefront](http://blog.wekeroad.com/tag/mvc/) is a good illustration.  If you have used the App-code folder to deploy new functionality were there any trade-offs or gotchas that should be considered?

UPDATE:

I found an [article in CoDe Magazine](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0609061&page=2) with this interesting passage:

> Your application-specific code can go
>   inline of the ASPX page or control, it
>   can go into a CodeBeside partial
>   class, or you can create completely
>   autonomous classes in the APP_CODE
>   folder. The APP_CODE folder is a
>   special folder in an ASP.NET 2.0
>   project and any non-page or
>   control-related source code in your
>   Web project must go into this folder.
>   ASP.NET treats the content of APP_CODE
>   like a library project and compiles
>   the content into a separate assembly.
>   This assembly is then referenced by
>   all of the page or directory-level
>   assemblies that ASP.NET creates from
>   your ASPX/ASCX pages that use any of
>   the classes defined in APP_CODE.

My question still stands - is a second AppDomain created that supports this libary, and if so are the impacts on performance minimal?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the details, but it will certainly be in different dynamic assemblies. A class can't be in another AppDomain. Only an instance of a class can be in another AppDomain, and then it's really a hassle to access from another AppDomain (only through remoting)